# Error loading Embedding Projector with Tensorboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard

I created a word to vector model using TensorFlow. I am trying to visualize it using the embedded projector, but it won't load. I'm able to display a graph of my neural network but when the projector tries to load, an error in my log says:

> projector_plugin.py:445 Failed Reading "checkpoint folder"

```
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(str(DIR_PATH/'saves/model'), session.graph)
config = projector.ProjectorConfig()
emb = config.embeddings.add()
emb.tensor_name = 'Word2Vec'
saver.save(session, str(DIR_PATH/'saves/model'))

projector.visualize_embeddings(writer, config)
```

I downgraded from TensorFlow v2.0 to v1.15 (after converting back to v1.x of course) and am still getting the same error:

> W0107 15:41:44.134179 14952 projector_plugin.py:445] Failed reading "...\saves\model"
>   W0107 15:41:44.136173 14952 projector_plugin.py:445] Failed reading "...\saves\model"

Comment: What OS are you using? At least for tensorboard 2.0.0, Windows users should use \\ for their directory paths.

Comment: I'm using Windows but because I'm using the builtin Path library it's automatically formatting the string

Comment: @SafeDev, Is your issue resolved now? Else, I suspect issue is in the line, `writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(str(DIR_PATH/'saves/model'), session.graph)`. To confirm that, just run the below code and it results in error, `DIR_PATH = 'a'
print(str(DIR_PATH/'saves/model'))`. Error is `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'`

Comment: @TensorflowSupport Is there a reason for the character 'a' before print, but I ran DIR_PATH = print(str(DIR_PATH/'saves/model')) and nothing happened